# How to make this symbol in html?

Tags: html

[image]

What is name called ?

And how to make this in html ?

Comment: I think that's just an alternating asterisk (*) and a low tilde (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+02F7).  So the HTML entity is `&#759;` or `&#x2F7;`

Comment: The asterisk might be a low asterisk (https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+204E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is simple Asterisk (*) & the other one is low tilde that can be written as ˷

So ......

```html
<span style="color: blue;">
&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*&#x2F7;*
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

~ this symbol is TILDE

```
<span>&#126;</span>
```

_*  This symbol is asterisk

```
<span>*</span>
```

check this code

```css
span{
color:blue;
font-size:50px;
}
body{
background:black;
}
```

```html
<span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span><span>&#126;</span>
<span>*</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tilde = `&#126;`
Asterisk = `&#42;`

Answer (score 0):

Okay. The easiest way to do that is by using '*' Asterisk sign,  tag, and '~'. What the  tag does is it makes the text smaller and lower it. For example, in chemistry, you might want to write O2. However, this is not the right format and you can make the number 2 lower and smaller by using the sub tag

For your code, we can use the following syntax

```html
<h1>*<sub>~</sub>*<sub>~</sub>*<sub>~</sub></h1>
```

The code above works. But as you can see, it is very messy and inefficient. We can do it much more better through JavaScript.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
     <h1 id="heading"></h1>
      <script>
        var text = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
          text[i] = "*<sub>~</sub>"
        }
        document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = text.join("")
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

If you want to make more "*"s and "~", you can change the number twenty (i < 20) to a bigger number.